# Hill-Chiffre - How can I find the Matrix $X$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, linear-cryptanalysis, hill-cipher

This is a problem of  classical cryptography: [Hill-Chiffre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher) 
Where the matrix $A$ is the clear message and the matrix $C$ the coded message.

How can I find the Matrix $X$?
Which method I can use?

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix} 
15 &4 & 17 \\
12 &20 & 19\\
0 &19 &8\\
14 &13 &18\\
10 &17 &24\\
15 &19 &14\\
18 &24 &18\\
19 &4 &12\\
\end{pmatrix}}_{A} \cdot
X = 
B\pmod{26} =
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
8 &3 &0\\
18 &1 &23\\
19 &13 &7\\
15 &5 &13\\
11 &23 &17\\
23 &19 &0\\
8 &12 &2\\
16 &24 &5
\end{pmatrix} }_{C}$$

Many thanks in advance.

---

Update - my attempt:

> $$X=(A^T \cdot A)^{-1}\cdot A^T \cdot B$$

$$A^T =$$
$\begin{pmatrix}
15  &4 &17\\
12 &20 &19\\
 0 &19 & 8\\
14 &13 &18\\
10 &17 &24\\
15 &19 &14\\
18 &24 &18\\
19  &4 &12\\
\end{pmatrix}^T=
\begin{pmatrix}
15 &12  &0 &14 &10 &15 &18 &19\\
 4 &20 &19 &13 &17 &19 &24 &4\\
17 &19  &8 &18 &24 &14 &18 &12\\
\end{pmatrix}
$

$$A^T \times A =$$ 
$\begin{pmatrix}
15 &12  &0 &14 &10 &15 &18 &19\\
 4 &20 &19 &13 &17 &19 &24 &4\\
17 &19  &8 &18 &24 &14 &18 &12\\
\end{pmatrix} \times
\begin{pmatrix}
15  &4 &17\\
12 &20 &19\\
 0 &19 & 8\\
14 &13 &18\\
10 &17 &24\\
15 &19 &14\\
18 &24 &18\\
19  &4 &12\\
\end{pmatrix}=$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1575 &1445 &1737\\
1445 &2188 &1988\\
1737 &1988 &2278\\
\end{pmatrix} (\mod 26) =
\begin{pmatrix}
15 &15 &21\\
15 &4 &12\\
21 &12 &16\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$(A^T \times A)^{-1} =$$
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
15 &15 &21\\
15 &4 &12\\
21 &12 &16\\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-20}{249} &\frac{1}{83}  &\frac{8}{83}\\
\frac{1}{83} &\frac{-67}{332} &\frac{45}{332}\\
\frac{8}{83} &\frac{45}{332}  &\frac{-55}{332}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$??$$

Comment: You have to work in the ring mod 26 and not in the field of rational numbers.

Comment: How? when.. $ \begin{pmatrix}
15 &15 &21\\
15 &4 &12\\
21 &12 &16\\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{-20}{249} &\frac{1}{83}  &\frac{8}{83}\\
\frac{1}{83} &\frac{-67}{332} &\frac{45}{332}\\
\frac{8}{83} &\frac{45}{332}  &\frac{-55}{332}
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: You're matrix is not invertible (mod 26). This shows that the pseudo-inverse method does not work in general.  Second, you seem to not understand modular arithmetic. You have first to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

First note that X must be a 3x3 matrix.
Then use the following  procedure:
Let $X_k$ be the k'th column of X and $C_k$ the k"th column of C.
Then you can solve the three equations $A X_k = C_k$ by Gaussian elimination:

Comment: There is no submatrix invertible.. :(   That is the problem

Comment: Ok, you are right. I modified my answer.

Comment: @Dario Gutierrez: Cryptostasis's modified method is most general. But the submatrix$$\widehat A=\begin{pmatrix}15&4&17\\12&20&19\\14&13&8\end{pmatrix}$$ of $A$ (keeping first, second and fourth lines) is invertible$\pmod{26}$. Then, obviously, $X=\widehat A^{-1}\cdot\widehat B$, where $\widehat B$ keeps the lines of $B$ kept in $\widehat A$.

Answer (score 1):

In general case, let $A\cdot X=B $. Then:
$${(A^T\cdot A)^{-1}}\cdot A^T\cdot A \cdot X={(A^T\cdot A)^{-1}}\cdot A^T \cdot B$$
So

> $$X={(A^T\cdot A)^{-1}}\cdot A^T \cdot B.$$

**Edit:** Another way to solve this problem is solving bellow equations which are derived from matrix multiplication law( when $A^T\cdot A$ is not invertible, this method is useful):

$$15x_{1,1}+4x_{2,1}+17x_{3,1}=8\\15x_{1,2}+4x_{2,2}+17x_{3,2}=3\\\vdots\\19x_{1,2}+4x_{2,2}+12x_{3,2}=24\\19x_{1,3}+4x_{2,3}+12x_{3,3}=5.$$

Comment: And when the matrix is not invertible?

Comment: The first method works if we replace $A^T$ with any matrix $C$ of the same dimension as $A^T$ is (that is, in the context, 8 lines and 3 columns), and such that $(C\cdot A)$ is invertible. Many choices of $C$ consisting of all-$0$ except a single $1$ in each line and at most one $1$ in each column qualify.